# How to fix Android Cannot get a dirty matrix error?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

An unknown error was output while using the soft keyboard

```
A/OpenGLRenderer: Cannot get a dirty matrix!
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 42843 (Thread-12), pid 15445
```

Why does such an error occur?? How do you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**do not call View#getLocationOnScreen or View#getMatrix on you worker thread**,

---

View#getLocationOnScreen or View#getMatrix will reset variable 'mPrimitiveFields.mMatrixOrPivotDirty' to false and check it, if true then crash;

Many APIs that run on the main thread like View#setScaleX/setScaleY/setAlpha will set variable 'mPrimitiveFields.mMatrixOrPivotDirty' to true

so if 'View#getLocationOnScreen or View#getMatrix' run on worker thread, it is possible to concurrently modify the variable 'mPrimitiveFields.mMatrixOrPivotDirty' and cause a crash

f you want a more detailed analysis, visit this:
https://www.jianshu.com/p/d6d3bb641198

---

http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_view_RenderNode.cpp
http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/libs/hwui/RenderProperties.h

View#getLocationOnScreen or View#getMatrix ->
android_view_RenderNode.cpp#android_view_RenderNode_getTransformMatrix ->

```
    static void android_view_RenderNode_getTransformMatrix(jlong renderNodePtr, jlong outMatrixPtr) {
        RenderNode* renderNode = reinterpret_cast<RenderNode*>(renderNodePtr);
        SkMatrix* outMatrix = reinterpret_cast<SkMatrix*>(outMatrixPtr);

        // call updateMatrix to reset 'mPrimitiveFields.mMatrixOrPivotDirty' to false
        renderNode->mutateStagingProperties().updateMatrix();
        // check 'mPrimitiveFields.mMatrixOrPivotDirty', if true then crash
        const SkMatrix* transformMatrix = renderNode->stagingProperties().getTransformMatrix();

        if (transformMatrix) {
            *outMatrix = *transformMatrix;
        } else {
            outMatrix->setIdentity();
        }
    }

    const SkMatrix* getTransformMatrix() const {
        LOG_ALWAYS_FATAL_IF(mPrimitiveFields.mMatrixOrPivotDirty, "Cannot get a dirty matrix!");
        return mComputedFields.mTransformMatrix;
    }
```