# React Native, Expo, Android. Abort message: 'Cannot get a dirty matrix!'

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I created react native app with expo. My build for android is ready and I wanted to publish it to PlayMarket. I tested my application with friends on different Android devices and emulators and so far everything was fine. But when I send my application for review it worked well on `Google Pixel 3` and `Samsung Galaxy S9`, but on `Nokia 1` I got a crash on map type change(on button click user is able to change type from `standard` to `hybrid`).

```
Native crash of ru.beautifulplaces.beautifulplaces
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Nokia/Frontier_00WW/FRT:8.1.0/O11019/00WW_1_33A:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 20170, tid: 21049, name: Thread-7  >>> ru.beautifulplaces.beautifulplaces <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Cannot get a dirty matrix!'
    r0 00000000  r1 00005239  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
    r4 00004eca  r5 00005239  r6 904d8724  r7 0000010c
    r8 00000000  r9 91312c00  sl 14058600  fp 12d2ae50
    ip 1404d2c8  sp 904d8710  lr b1b2e8e5  pc b1b283ce  cpsr 200f0030
```

I tried to reproduce this problem on different devices and emulators without success. I don't have physical Nokia 1 device and on Android Studio I didn't find such emulator so I created custom emulator with params of original Nokia 1 and everything is fine.

What should I do in this case? I don't even understand why this problem arises.

System settings: Nokia 1, Android 8.1 (SDK 27), Open GL ES (3.1), RAM 1024 mb.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? i got the same issue

Comment: @IsmaelRodriguez I haven't found a solution. As I understand sometimes it happens especially on low end android devices, but my app was succesfully published by google and I didn't hear about crashes from users so I think it is rather the exception than the rule

Comment: see if this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649304/how-to-fix-android-cannot-get-a-dirty-matrix-error/71101741#71101741

Answer (score 0):

On my device the same problem, I tried many methods, up to flashing the device, but it did not help. I did the following: I generated a new `react-native` project using `react-native init`, and transferred all the files from the `expo` project to it.